# Check if "data" attribute contains A PART of input value (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this way I only find the needed div, if the `"data-content"` contains the **complete** word.

```
var input = "TestText123";
var found = $("#list").find(".box[data-name='" + input + "']").addClass("found");
```

But I also want to find this div if my "input" just contains **a correct part** of it (min. 5 characters).

It's interesting, that this would work, if I don't use the "data" method (but I need it).

```
var found = $("#list").find(".box:contains('" + input + "')").addClass("found");
```

How to modify the "data" method in jQuery, like the way I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an asterisk before the equal sign: `[data-name*=...]`.

Side note: the argument of `addClass` should not have a dot, so just `addClass("found")`:

```js
var input = "TestText123";
var found = $("#list").find(".box[data-name*='" + input + "']").addClass("found");
```

```css
.found { background: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
    <li class ="box" data-name="WhatTestText12345">should match</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That did the trick, good to know, big thx for help! Btw., the dot at "addClass" was just a careless mistake by myself, but also thx ;).